# How to disable my registration page from re-displaying on press of the back button

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

In my application I have a registration page, I want the user to fill her credentials and click a picture too. Once completed and the user is registered I want to prevent access to this particular page on press of back button. I had previously used

```
      android:noHistory="true"
```

But when I start the camera intent with above line of code in my manifest declaration of the said activity I lose my data sent from the camera intent. I want suggestions as in if there is any other way to skip the page on press of the back button. Will overriding the back button be feasible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the Intent instance like this:

```
Intent showActivity = new Intent(CURRENT_ACTIVITY.this, TARGET_ACTIVITY.class);
showActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(showActivity);
finish();
```

The `android:noHistory="true"` attribute in the Manifest removes the trace of the `Activity` from the `Activity Stack`

**EDIT:**

You should use the above piece of code only **after** you have finished the Camera Intent code. That is, **after** the *Registration Process* is completed and you now want to, say, the Main Activity where the actual app will be in use. This code will naturally fail for the Camera Intent. ;-)

Comment: You mean that I should declare the intent of the registration page like above? I am going to try this. Thanks mate :)

Comment: @ChronicallyInsane.: That is correct. I use this for my splash screen without it ever showing up again after backing out.

Comment: @ChronicallyInsane.: You are welcome fella. Glad to have helped. :-)